# R: Histogram with custom breaks for custom x axis range

Tags: r, histogram

I need to plot a vector of numbers. Let's say these numbers range from 0 to 1000. I need to make a histogram where the x axis goes from 100 to 500, and I want to specify the number of bins to be 10. How do I do this?

I know how to use xlim and break separately, but I don't know how to make a given number of bins inside the custom range.

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good question actually! I was bothered by this all the time but finally your question has kicked me to finally solve it :-)

Well, in this case we cannot simply do `hist(x, xlim = c(100, 500), breaks = 9)`, as the `breaks` refer to the whole range of x, not related to `xlim` (in other words, `xlim` is used only for plotting, not for computing the histogram and setting the actual breaks). This is a clear flaw of the `hist` function and there is no simple remedy found in the documentation.

I think the easiest way out is to "xlim" the values *before* they go to the `hist` function:

```
x <- runif(1000, 0, 1000) # example data
hist(x[x > 100 & x < 500], breaks = 9)
```

`breaks` should be number of cells minus one.

For more info see [`?hist`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/hist)

Comment: I'm glad to know that I'm not the only one who thought this to be a flaw/limitation of HIST function.