# R shiny - working with histogram parameters in reactive({}) setting

Tags: r, plot, shiny, histogram

I am trying to set the x-axis limits of my reactive histograms in a shiny app to be constant. For example, regardless of the data i simulate, I would always like to have 200 breaks between 0 and 3000 (any frequencies spilling over 3000, or below 0, should be truncated out).

Is there a simple way of getting this done?

I've tried the following based on an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420399/r-histogram-with-custom-breaks-for-custom-x-axis-range):

```
histSims <- reactive({
        #return
        hist(beanSims()[beanSims() > 1 & beanSims < 3000],
             breaks = 200,
             prob = T)
```

followed by

```
output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
        plot(histSims()                 
      ))
    })
```

But I get

```
Error: comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code:

```
histSims <- reactive({
            #return
            beanSims_local<-beanSims()
            beanSims_local<-beanSims_local[beanSims_local> 1 & beanSims_local< 3000]
            hist(beanSims_local,
                 breaks = 200,
                 prob = T)
```